# Can't change to CloudFlare because dns is hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname, cloudflare

I want to setup cloudflare but the problem is that my ns for the site is also hostname i.e ns1 and ns2.designzzz.com
the problem is that if i change the nameserver to cloudflare's in my godaddy how will it affect my other sites using this ns1 and ns2 on the server ?
What should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

When you change your NS to Cloudflare you need to setup your DNS records there also. GoDaddy should be only delegating DNS resolution to Cloudflare servers.

Comment: Can you tell me how please?

Comment: On the DNS section of your domain in Cloudflare you need to add all current GoDaddy DNS records as Cloudflare is going to resolve them from now on. Don't remember if you have a export option there or you need to add it one by one.

Comment: i am really not sure because on the cloud flare panel there are options like ns, cname, a etc.. i am no tech guy and my hosting company is asking me to ask cloudflare, cloudflare is saying they can't change anything, i have to do my self. pff

Comment: You should not modify NS servers on Cloudflare, only add all other records in GoDaddy (CNAME, A, TXT, etc...) to Cloudflare. When you are all done then you should delegate your domain in GoDaddy to Cloudflare NS servers.

Comment: I don't see such records in my godaddy, but they are on my whm of server. only hostnames and nameservers available on godaddy